# React Helmet not updating meta title tag

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, meta-tags, react-helmet

I've been setting my react.js SPA's page titles by doing:

```
document.title = {some title}
```

...so far and it worked fine. Now, I also wanted to update the `meta` `title` tag and so I installed [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).
In my component, I've imported `Helmet` from the library and did:

```
render() {
  {/* ... */}
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{docTitle}</title>
        <meta name="title" content={docTitle} />
      </Helmet>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When opening the page, I saw that the document title is properly updated, but when inspecting the elements in the browser, I noticed that `<meta name="title"` is not being updated, while a few lines down, `<title>` *is* updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my `<head>` code, I added the following tag in the `index.html` file:

```
<meta name="title" content="Default Title">
```

When updating that meta tag using react-helmet, I still saw that tag un-updated in the index.html file when inspecting the elements in my browser.
However, what I did not notice, is that at the very bottom of the `<head>`, Helmet apparently added this tag instead:

```
<meta name="title" content="Default Title" data-react-helmet="true">
```

I'm guessing (and hoping) that this will be crawled by search engine bots.

**Update:**
After some time has passed, I can verify that Facebook and Google properly read helmet's title tag.

Answer (score 22):

It's not documented in the readme, but you have to add `data-react-helmet="true"` to your meta tags that you want to replace with react-helmet. So as an example, in your `index.html`, your meta tag should be updated to look like this:

```
 <meta name="title" content="Default Title" data-react-helmet="true">
```

This should be in the readme, I don't know why it's not, and I saw a comment that someone had already opened a PR to add it.